# Problem starting old programs created in VS6

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I have some old programs that I created 7-8 years ago in C++ in Visual Studio 6.0.

I tried to start them today, but I had no luck. When starting up the program (or any other program I created at the time), I get the following error message:

[image: VS6.0 Error message]

I can see at least that MFC42D.DLL and MSVCP60D.DLL is present in the program folder, but honestly I do not remember what is required to start these programs any more, and I obviously do not have VS6 installed on my current machine.

Do anyone know what this error message mean, and what I can do to resolve it? I would love to start up these old programs again to see what they look like :)

**EDIT**

I got a step further now, after I put a new DLL, but now the problem is that Direct X 8 is not getting set up properly. I thought DirectX was backwards compatible, but do I have to install DX8 as well? Will it work having two DirectX versions installed at the same time?

Comment: You're running the *debug* version of the executable. Do you not have the release version?

Comment: I think I probably only compiled the debug variant, and not the release one. Will that cause any additional problems?

Comment: No, that's just why you're seeing the message. The debug version of the CRT does some extra checks to facilitate debugging. You'll still have to fix the code that's causing the error if you want everything to work correctly. ;-)

Comment: But the code was running fine some 7 years ago on my old old developement machine. So I guess that there was some files on that machine in some common directory that I no longer have, and that are required by the applications I'm trying to run. All of them are DirectX (Some also DirectDraw that is deprecated) based, so I thought that might be the problem.

Comment: The error it's showing looks like a memory corruption error; either you're calling a function with the wrong calling convention (`cdecl` when you should be using `stdcall`, for example) or there's something overwriting the stack. I don't think either of those are the result of a missing DLL dependency, but that doesn't explain why it worked on your old machine. I'd say the way to solve the problem would be to attach a debugger to the running process and see where it's being brought to its knees.

Comment: Yup, I guess it's no other way than using some time if I want to get this to work, so then it's just a matter of when I get the time to do that ;) Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a program like [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), that would show you all the DLLs that your programs need.  Then you would have to find all those DLLs.

Another option is to find a copy of VisualStudio 6 and install in on your machine.

A third option is to get a more recent version of Visual Studio, and to try to recompile your code.

Comment: I don't know. Your screen shot did not show up at first, so I answered based on your comment about the DLLs. However, given how old your programs are, missing DLLs are definitely something to check for.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 installed, so I could give it a go there I suppose, but I don't want to waste a day getting this to work either :) I'll try the dependency walker option first :)

Comment: I got a step further now, and the program started but stopped when initializing due to DirectX 8. See my edit to the original question. Maybe you have a clue to that also :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about DirectX.